# SQL Server issue when grouping by year,month, day

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the below query where I get the past 6 rows from column 'FileSize' and total them into separate column called 'previous'. What I need is to group the results by year,month, day.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY,CompleteTime )
  , SUM(ja.FileSize)
  , SUM(FileSize) OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY,CompleteTime ) ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as previous
FROM Jobs_analytics ja
WHERE CompleteTime Between '2020-7-13 00:00:00' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY,CompleteTime )
```

However SQL wants me to add the `FileSize`  to the group by clause. But When I do that I get every file in the results set.   Since `SUM(FileSize) OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY,CompleteTime ) ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as previous` was in a `SUM` function I didn't think I needed to include it in the group by clause?

Is there anyway I can group my results set by year,month, day?

Comment: Have you tried SUM(SUM(FileSize))?

Comment: now I feel like a idiot , yea that worked place that in the answer and I give you the credit

Comment: No worries, it's happened to all of us.

Comment: Are you ever going to run this for more than a full month at a time? If so then that's not the right grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expecting to sum the column `FileSize` when you want to sum the sum:

```
SUM(SUM(FileSize)) OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY,CompleteTime ) ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as previous
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner `sum()` takes care of the group aggregate. The outer `sum() over ()` is the analytic function that looks over the prior rows (which are now grouped and summed themselves.)

```
SELECT
    CAST(CompleteTime AS DATE), SUM(FileSize) AS TotalSize,
    SUM(SUM(FileSize)) OVER (
        ORDER BY CAST(CompleteTime AS DATE)
        ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS Previous
FROM Jobs_analytics
WHERE CompleteTime BETWEEN '2020-07-13 00:00:00' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY CAST(CompleteTime AS DATE);
```

Be careful with `datepart(day, ...)` as it's going to return a value from 1 to 31 and will collide with other months/years once you expand your date range enough to cover multiple dates falling on the same day of month.